# Is it possible to use ASP.NET Core within an F# fsx script?

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, f#-scripting

Found that the question was pondered a few years ago: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8688

My code looks like

```
#r "nuget: Microsoft.NETCore.App"
#r "nuget: Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref"
#r "nuget: Microsoft.AspNetCore"

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder

let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use ASP.NET Core within an F# fsx script?

No you can't do that, directly referencing ASP.NET Core within an F# fsx script isn't officially supported, but you can try that manually as a workarounds.

You would require to load assembly reference `dll` file then need to open it.

Let's say, you want to refer following dll file from your directory:

[image]

Use #r "path/to/assembly.dll" to reference assemblies manually.

Then you have to locate required ASP.NET Core assemblies in your .NET Core installation

For insctance: If I want to refer `Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll` from the above directory, then you can do as following:

```
#r "path/to/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.8.0.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll"

open Microsoft.AspNetCore
```

**Note:** I would highly recommend you to [refer this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tools/fsharp-interactive/#referencing-assemblies-on-disk-with-f-interactive)